# Mingw C++ compiler in batch

Tags: c++, batch-file, mingw

I'm trying to make a quick c++ compiler in batch, but it keeps on giving me 2 errors.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

g++: error: missing filename after '-o'

I don't know where these errors are coming from since I double checked my path that I was inputting , and it worked fine on normal command line, and I have a var after the -o that acts as a filename. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out.

Here is my Code

```
@echo off
set /p path = "Path of Program "
set /p file = "filename "
set /p exe = " exe name "
cd \
cd %path%
g++ %file% -IC:\Development\i686-w64-mingw32\include -L C:\Development\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o %exe%
pause
```

Comment: You can't put a space between the variable name and the equals symbol with the `SET` command.  Remove the space.

Comment: I would also highly advise you not overwrite the system variable `PATH`.  Make a different variable name for path like `ppath`.

Comment: what about the g++ error missing filename after -o?

Comment: I know nothing about `g++`.  I do know the proper syntax for `batch-files`.  I assumed that fixing the `SET` commands would have fixed all your errors.